# Pads very close together, no space for guard ring? What should I do?

Tags: pcb, layout, trace, pad, clearance

**Introduction to the problem**

I use an op amp to buffer the output of an in amp and to drive the input of an ADC, so the signal path looks basically like this: in amp -> op amp -> ADC

The device of interest is the ADA4805-1 Operational Amplifier. This op amp comes in a 6-pin SC-70 package (dimensions and pinout are shown in the image below).

[image: Dimensions and pinout of the ADA4805-1]
In my particular application, the pins are connected as follows:

- Pin 1 : connected to ADC input (max. 3.3V)
- Pin 2 : connected to GND (0V, single-supply)
- Pin 3 : connected to InAmp output via an anti-aliasing filter (max. 3.3V)
- Pin 4 : connected to Pin 1 (unity gain buffer configuration)
- Pin 5 : connected to 5V (shutdown functionality not used)
- Pin 6 : connected to 5V

Please also refer to the schematic below (only the relevant part is shown, A13 is the op amp).

[image: Relevant part of the schematic]

The input of the op amp is a high impedance node. Thus, I want to utilize a guard ring to prevent any relevant leakage currents. I already utilized this technique for the inputs of the instrumentation amplifier A11. The instrumentation amplifier is an AD8422. Its pinout makes the routing of the guard ring very easy (pins 1-4 are all on a very similar potential, so simply encircle the whole input with a single guard ring).
The pinout of the op amp on the other hand makes it very difficult to route the guard ring. I want to use the guard ring to encircle the positive input (pin 3) of the op amp, which is a high impedance node, and drive the guard ring with the output of the op amp, which is a low impedance node and on the same potential.
[image: Schematic with guard ring]

**The actual question**

The problem with the guard ring is, that there is not enough space to route it between two pads of the ADA4805-1 op amp. The picture below shows that there is not enough space between two pads of the ADA4805-1 op amp, even if I only use a 3 mil wide guard ring trace (which is ridiculously narrow, usually I prefer traces > 6 mil). The grid shown in the picture is a 2 mil-grid. Please note: The picture does not show a finished layout, it is just there to illustrate the problem. Nothing else is routed on that picture and the guard ring is not connected to the output of the op amp yet.

So, what should I do about this? I could simply omit the guard ring, but that would probably cause leakage currents. However, I am not sure how serious the leakage-current-problem is, since the maximum voltage is only 3.3 V. The PCB will have a ground plane, but there will be no ground plane below the ADA4805-1 op amp to reduce leakage. So my main concern is any leakage to / from the supply pins of the op amp.
[image: Picture of the routing problem]

Comment: I would define high impedance as 500k or higher. For any reasonable value of R16, this is not a high-impedance circuit. No guard band is necessary.

Comment: @Mattman9422 Thank you! I think I was too focused on the fact, that the input of an operational amplifier usually requires a guard ring because of the high input impedance. But you are right, in this case, the impedance is not that high. The exact value of R16 will be determined in-lab but it will be less than 5kOhm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of the instrumentation amplifier is low impedance, guarding should not be necessary for A13.

Any leakage currents at that node will have an insignificant effect as the negative feedback within the instrumentation amplifier will avoid any change of the voltage.

You don't state the value of the resistance in the RC filter between the two amplifiers but to minimize leakage effects I would not recommend more than a few kilohm.

You don't indicate the part number of the instrumentation amplifier.

Comment: Just a bit more info.  With an input offset voltage spec of 125 uV (max), and input bias current of ~0.5 uA, this device really isn't a high precision amp.  It seems to strike a good balance between speed and DC characteristics.  With DC specs like this, a guard ring won't improve things, and could make things worse (look at the data sheet recommendations about not having ground planes near the inpt and output pins.

Comment: @Kevin White Thank you for your answer! 

The exact values for the RC-filter will be determined in-lab after building the first prototype. The RC-filter is primarily used as an anti-aliasing filter, so its corner frequency depends on the sampling frequency and other parameters of the ADC. 

The instrumentation amplifier is an AD8422.

Comment: @florian_aust - the capacitor can be as large as you want but high resistor values could cause errors due to leakage and opamp input current.

Comment: @SteveSh  Thank you! Yes, the purpose of the OpAmp ist to have good precision and speed. Since there is no OpAmp that has perfect precision and super high speed at the same time, this OpAmp is a compromise. It serves as a buffer for the ADC, so the signal can settle within the short acquisition time of the ADC. Otherwise the limited bandwidth of the instrumentation amplifier, which is operated with high gain, would be a problem.

Regarding the ground planes: The guard ring would be operated at the output voltage of the OpAmp, not at GND-Level, so no additional error would be introduced.

Comment: Would you also omit the guard ring of the instrumentation amplifier 8422?
It amplifies the signal of a 350Ohm strain gauge.

Comment: @florian_aust - When using a 350-ohm strain gauge a guard would almost certainly not be required although wouldn't hurt. A nanoamp of leakage would only cause an error of 350nV. Less than the drift of the amplifier.

Comment: @Kevin White I will keep the guard ring, since the error caused by the leakage current will be amplified by the instrumentation amplifier (if its differential). So an error of 350nV will turn into an error of 0.35mV with a gain of 1000. That is of course a worst-case scenario.

Comment: @florian_aust - there is no harm in leaving the guard ring, but realize that any error there will probably be far less than that caused by other errors such as thermoelectric potentials or the drift of the instrumentation amplifier.